# Does the Shopify template system have an admin only variable?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to be able to show product edit links on the product pages of a Shopify site.

But I only want the link to appear to users who are logged in as admins.

Is this possible in the Liquid syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, this is still not possible.

[See here for more info:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470990/1367622)

> Currently there isn't [a way to do this with liquid]. You could perhaps try inspecting cookies and stuff
>   to see if there's some identifying information that would let you know
>   if the user is an admin, but it would be fragile...

An alternative option is to use [customer accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483251/1367622) with an 'admin' tag.